Análisis de sentimientos de tuits en r
Quiero hacer un análisis de sentimientos en r de una colección tuits que están en español, inglés, francés, italiano y chino, he limpiado los datos y he convertido el archivo original xlsx a txt para realizar el análisis de sentimientos empezándolo con estas líneas de código:
#4. ANÁLISIS DE SENTIMIENTOS
#Creamos un vector con los distintos idiomas
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
idiomas <- c("spanish","italian","english","french")

sentimientospalabras <- get_nrc_sentiment(pfizer_palabras, lang="idiomas")
sentimientosfrases <- get_nrc_sentiment(pfizer_frases, lang="idiomas")

Me da este error:

Error in value[[jvseq[[jjj]]]] : subscript out of bounds

Si alguien me puede echar una mano, se lo agradecería enormemente. Saludos

Este es un caso donde se hace imposible responder sin un [mcve], prueba armar un ejemplo con datos que reproduzca el error, con eso seguramente podremos darte alguna ayuda

Tu error está en lang="idiomas" ya que idiomas entre comillas no es un valor válido para la función get_nrc_sentiment, en su lugar, debe ser uno de los valores contenidos en el vector idiomas. No estoy seguro si se puede usar un vector ya que la documentación dice a string y no un vector para lang
